# Tomcat not able to access resource (Windows) Getting access denied

Tags: java, tomcat

[image: Getting access denied]

Getting access denied while reading the JKS file in **Tomcat 7**. I have given full permission to all the users.Changed the installation location.But getting the same exception. It work fine fine with **Tomcat 6** on same machine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to have specified the keystore file as a directory.

The access-denied error you are seeing is what you get when you attempt to open a directory as if it were a file.  You can't do this to a directory.

Have you specified the location of the keystore in your `server.xml` file as follows?

```xml
<Connector ...
           keystoreFile="E:/apache-tomcat-7.0.42" ... />
```

If so, specify the name of the file (quite probably `.keystore`) instead:

```xml
<Connector ...
           keystoreFile="E:/apache-tomcat-7.0.42/.keystore" ... />
```